# iOS 13 - Right Bar Button Item goes offset in Modal Sheet presentation

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13

I have this strange problem with iOS 13 and its new sheet cards style modal presentation.
 
From ViewController1 I modal present ViewController2 embedded in a NavigationController, and everything works fine.
 
From ViewController2, I then modal present ViewController3 embedded in a NavigationController, and I get the Right Bar Button offset.
 
 
Here is a video of the problem: does anybody have a fix?

[image: What am I doing wrong?]

Main View Controller

```
import UIKit

let vc1identifier = "vc1identifier"
let vc2identifier = "vc2identifier"

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func tap1(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let navigation = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vc1identifier) as? UINavigationController,
        let nextVC = navigation.contentViewController as? UnoViewController {

        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}

extension UIViewController {
var contentViewController: UIViewController {
    if let navcon = self as? UINavigationController {
        return navcon.visibleViewController!
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
}
```

Second View Controller

```
import UIKit

class UnoViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    barButton.title = "GotoVC2"
}

@IBAction func pressThis(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if let navigation = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vc2identifier) as? UINavigationController,
        let nextVC = navigation.contentViewController as? DueViewController {

        self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pepo, can you provide a standalone code example that shows this behaviour in action?

Comment: Hi @BenSower I added the source code, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue.

Solution is easy, you just need to tell navigationbar it needs layout like this

```
 override public func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
       navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
    }
 }
```